# Why is the object name used in the method of the object instead of this?

Tags: javascript

In the following piece of code `store.nextId` and `store.cache` is used in the `add` method. I was wondering why not `this`?

```
var store = {
  nextId: 1,

  cache: {},

  add: function(fn) {
    if (!fn.id) {
      fn.id = store.nextId++;
      return !!(store.cache[fn.id] = fn);
    }
  }
};
```

Thanks to everyone who answered my question!

Comment: looks like sloppy coding to me...

Comment: There's nothing in that fragment of code which would require it. Any answer would just be speculating as to the author's reasoning.

Comment: @Quentin there is - it's bad practise to refer to an object's externally referencing variable names from inside that object.

Comment: @Quentin, when a coding style has only drawbacks it's not a coding style but a mistake... (like this one)

Comment: It's from a book guys, Secrets of the javascript Ninja, by the guy who coded or did something with jQuery. It actually has nothing to do with if it is a good or a bad coding practice.

Comment: You should have mentioned it before, and it's still wrong, maybe he did want to dive to deep at that stage?

Comment: @gdoron Dive deep to where? It's never explained why it says store.nextId, so that's why I ask here. It's just an example of how to store functions and it's just... there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semantics of using `store` are slightly different from those of using `this`, in that if you ever treat `store.add` as a regular function (e.g., passing it as an argument to a different function), then using `store` means that the function will still refer to `store`, whereas using `this` would instead cause it to refer to the global object.

Of course, the tradeoff is that this `add` method will always refer to the object *currently* identified by the variable `store`, rather than to the object that was originally identified by that variable. Assuming that this method is really always supposed to refer to the same object, a way to get the benefit of both approaches is to use an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
var store = (function () {
    var store = {
        ...  // exactly as defined in the code you posted, but now 'store'
             // refers to the *local* variable 'store', which can never change
    };
    return store;
})();
```

That said, it wouldn't surprise me if the author of this code did not have any specific use-case in mind, and simply felt that it was clearer to refer to `store` as `store` even inside its methods.

Answer (score 2):

The author of that code *may* have a good reason for this, but on the face of it this looks like sloppy, naive coding.

IMHO, functions within a JS object should never depend on the external variable name (or names) by which that object is known.

If the code used `this` it would be possible to do this:

```
var storeCopy = store;
store = null;
storeCopy.add(...);      // still works
```

With the internal reference to `store` in place this code cannot be modularised for re-use.

Comment: Though, the value of `this` doesn't necessarily have a better guarantee to it than `store` would offer, since it depends on external (calling) code as well.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems completely wrong, unless I'm misunderstanding what it's trying to say . . .

Comment: @ruakh it wasn't wrong as such, but it was confusing so I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case (where you have methods on a names variable that is in scope), either `this` or `store` work fine.

I prefer `this` as it is more portable — you can move the object definition or renamed `store` and not have to change any code inside of it.

Sometimes, however, you do might see a reason to have a global name. An example is if you are creating a function that you will assign as an event handler where it will be *bound* to a different object.  When a function is bound to a different object, that means `this` will refer to that other object.  If you needed a reference back to `store`, you would need to use it's global name, or a closure reference. The second is usually preferred, again for portability.